# Property 'id' does not exist on type '[Task]'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write simple API using Typescript which performs CURD operations and I'm getting below error in the code for Adding Task. I have created interface with all the required properties in it. Below is the code can you please guide as I feel i'm missing something here. I have read below article in stack overflow but no luck.

[Property id does not exist on type string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41269866/property-id-does-not-exist-on-type-string)

**Error**
Property 'id' does not exist on type '[Task]'

[Erro screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nsqj0.png)

**Code**
**ITask.ts**

```
export default interface Task{
    id: number,
    title: string,
    completed: boolean
}
```

**Controller.ts**

```
import Task from '../src/ITask';
import fs from  "fs";
import path from "path";
import { ServerResponse, IncomingMessage } from 'http';

const getTask = (req:IncomingMessage, res:ServerResponse) =>{
    return fs.readFile(
        path.join(__dirname,"store.json"),"utf-8",
        (err, data) =>{
            if(err){
                res.writeHead(500,{"Content-Type" : "application/json"});
                res.end(
                    JSON.stringify({
                    success: false,
                    error: err,
                }));
            } else{
                res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "application/json"});
                res.end(JSON.stringify({
                    success: true,
                    message:JSON.parse(data),
                }));
            }
        }
    );
}

const addTask = (req:IncomingMessage, res:ServerResponse) =>{

        let data ="";

        req.on("data" ,(chunk)=>{
            data+= chunk.toString();
        });
    
        req.on("end",()=>{
            let task = JSON.parse(data);
    
        })
    fs.readFile(
        path.join(__dirname,"store.json"),"utf-8",
        (err,data) =>{
            if(err){
                res.writeHead(500,{"Content-Type":"application/json"});
                res.end(
                    JSON.stringify({
                        success: false,
                        error: err
                    }
                    )
                );
            }else{

                // no error, get the current tasks
         let tasks : [Task] = JSON.parse(data);

          let latest_id = tasks.reduce(
           (max = 0, task: Task) => (task.id > max ? task.id : max),
           0
         );
         // increment the id by 1
         tasks.id = latest_id + 1;
                

            }
        }
        )

}
```

**store.json**

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Learn React",
      "completed": false
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Learn Redux",
      "completed": false
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Learn React Router",
      "completed": false
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "title": "Cooking Lunch",
      "completed": true
    }
 ]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

tasks is an array, typescript tells you this with the `[` `]` in the error message. You need to get an element of it to get at the `Task` type.